# Conditional statement and inline styles - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im trying to switch a background image out based upon the window size...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYdZox

```
function resize(){
  var dbg = $('.full-screen-banner').data('dbg');
  var mbg = $('.full-screen-banner').data('mbg');
  if ($(window).width() < 768) { console.log('less than');
      $(".full-screen-banner").css('background-image', mbg);
  } else {
    $(".full-screen-banner").css('background-image', dbg);
  }
}
resize();
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Im using the above, the console log works fine but the inline style wont change?

Comment: `@media` queries will do just fine

Comment: You can use a CSS media query for this. It is more semantic and will perform *much* better than JS. You can use the `attr()` function to read the `data` attribute in CSS, if you prefer to do it that way.

Comment: Meqia queries would be great, but that's not an option in this case unfortunately

Comment: Can you tell us why exactly?

Comment: Im working with a custom CMS that allows for 2 images to be uploaded to 1 module. 1 image is then set as a background using inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this, where you use `url(...)` with the image source path

```
$(".full-screen-banner").css('background-image', 'url('+dbg+')');
```